# Live coding in AspNet Core

Tags: asp.net-core, livecoding

I was wondering, if it is possible to do live coding using Asp.Net core similar how it is possible to do this in node.js using nodemon. I am trying to learn asp.net core and I find the code-compile-debug cycle very slow and inconvenient.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch ;)

Comment: @Tseng This looks good. Thank you! I will try this out.

Comment: dotnet watch is a great option if you're working from the command line. Visual Studio will also automatically recompile your project when requests come in if you're running without debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is possible to do live coding using **ASP.NET Core** similar how it is possible to do this in **Node.js** using nodemon?

Yes, it is. You can use the `dotnet watch` command. This command will allow you to do "live coding". In also works with tests, i.e.; if you find a bug and you can fix the bug and watch will detect the changes, recompile your code and re-execute the tests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch

Comment: I tried to follow the tutorial and with the latest version of  Visual Studio (2017 RC) the projects.json is gone and so the tools section in it where I need to add the nuget definition. Any ideas how this can be done with the eliminated projects.json_

Comment: Nuget global config